# Tomcat / Jdbc / The statement did not return a result set

Tags: sql-server, tomcat, stored-procedures, jdbc

We are using JDBC to exec a stored procedure (SQL Server) returning resultset. 
The connection is retrieve from Tomcat pooling.

It's work fine.

But, after a while (several days or weeks after application start), we have the following error on the executeQuery from PreparedStatement :

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement did not return a result set.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:408)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:350)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:285)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor91.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractQueryReport$StatementProxy.invoke(AbstractQueryReport.java:235)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
```

Exception appended on executeQuery (see beelow)

```
final PreparedStatement stmt = super.getConnection().prepareStatement("exec sp_storeprocedure ?, ?");
stmt.setString(1, "value1");
stmt.setString(2, "value2");
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Come on, at least show us some Java code.

Comment: Exception appended on executeQuery. But I don't think there is a problem with the code. It's propably something about SQL SERVER.

final PreparedStatement stmt = super.getConnection().prepareStatement("exec sp_storeprocedure ?, ?");
stmt.setString(1, "value1");
stmt.setString(2, "value2");
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

Comment: No, include this code in your question, formatted with four or more spaces.